# Restrict checkServerTrusted just for initialization of connection with my server

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, x509trustmanager

CheckServerTrusted is called when initialization with my server is made.

However checkServerTrusted is also called when Google maps are initialized.

Is it somehow possible to restrict checkServerTrusted just for initialization of connection to my server?

So I want to checkServerTrusted just to be called when initialization of connection with my server is made.

//CustomOkHttpClient

```
  public static OkHttpClient.Builder getCustomOkHttpClient() {
        try {

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init((KeyStore)null);

            TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
            final X509TrustManager origTrustmanager = (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0];

            TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return origTrustmanager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                        }

                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                            origTrustmanager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                        }

                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                            origTrustmanager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                            
                    }
            };
```

//ApiClient

```
 val builder = CustomOkHttpClient.getCustomOkHttpClient();
            client = builder.build()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Is this a dev server? Or you want to validate your server but have untrusted connections to Google?

Comment: The code in the trustmanagers below should be an ok starting point to implementing your own with knowledge of the server.  Can you just look at the certificates from the handshake or do you need to get called during the handshake?

Answer (score 0):

You can allowlist specific servers with invalid certificates using

```
  val clientCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
      .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
      .addInsecureHost(server.hostName)
      .build()

  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .sslSocketFactory(clientCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificates.trustManager)
      .build()
```

The code in https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/f8fd4d08decf697013008b05ad7d2be10a648358/okhttp-tls/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/tls/internal/InsecureAndroidTrustManager.kt shows you how to implement on Android

For JDK https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/f8fd4d08decf697013008b05ad7d2be10a648358/okhttp-tls/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/tls/internal/InsecureExtendedTrustManager.kt